# Node JS child process error The "message" argument must be defined

Tags: node.js, express, child-process, node-ssh

While Trying to use child Process to have a multiple ssh connection I got this error`your text`
`

```
inside process.on
node:internal/child_process:754
      throw new ERR_MISSING_ARGS('message');
      ^

TypeError [ERR_MISSING_ARGS]: The "message" argument must be specified
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:754:13)
    at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Sublist3e\functions\subdomains.js:16:13)
```

`

I was trying to connect to ssh using child process.Let me know if this is possible and help me find the solution

```
process.on('message', (message) => {
    let subfind = findSubs(message.URl);
    console.log('inside process.on')
    // send the results back to the parent process
    process.send(subfind);
    // kill the child process
    process.exit();
})


function findSubs(URl) {
    ssh
        .connect({
            host: '192.168.199.131',
            username: 'aavash',
            password: 'admin'
        })
        .then(() => {
        
            return ssh.execCommand(`subfinder -d ${URl} -o /home/aavash/Desktop/${URl}.txt`)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result.stdout)
                })
        })
        .then(() => {
            // Local, Remote
            return ssh.getFile(`C://Users/dell/Desktop/Sublist3e/Subdomains/${URl}.txt`, `/home/aavash/Desktop/${URl}.txt`).then(function (Contents) {
                console.log("The File's contents were successfully downloaded")
            })
         })
         .then(()=>  {
                          
             fs.readFileSync(`C://Users/dell/Desktop/Sublist3e/Subdomains/${URl}.txt`, function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                subs = data.toString().split("\n");
    

                console.log(subs)
                for(i in subs) {
                    console.log(subs[i]);
                }    
               
            })
         })    
        
     }
```

I call the above file as shown below:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  URl='hackerrank.com'
  const child = childProcess.fork('./functions/subdomains.js');
child.send(URl)
child.on('message', (message) => res.render('subdomains', { Domain: URl, subdomains: subs }) )
})
```

There might be multiple erros in the code

Comment: You are not returning anything from `findSubs()`

Comment: pls accept the answer if it’s working, if not let me know what’s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `findSubs`. Therefore the call to `findSubs` in `let subfind = findSubs(message.URl);` returns undefined which you are passing in  `process.send(subfind);`

```
process.on('message', (message) => {
    /// findSubs(message.URl); returns undefined 
    let subfind = findSubs(message.URl);
    /// subfind = undefined


    console.log('inside process.on')
    // send the results back to the parent process


    /// this line amounts to process.send(undefined); because subfind = undefined
    process.send(subfind);
    ///Hence you get the error: TypeError [ERR_MISSING_ARGS]: The "message" argument must be specified


    // kill the child process
    process.exit();
})
```

Return the contents of the file from the function `findSubs()`.
Use async await for the ssh calls and the file reading in the function `findSubs()` and  return the contents of the file.

also await `findSubs()` in the message event callback of the child process

```
process.on('message', async (message) => {
    // await findSubs here
    let subfind = await findSubs(message.URl);
    console.log('inside process.on')
    // send the results back to the parent process
    process.send(subfind);
    // kill the child process
    process.exit();
})
```

Comment: I tried returning subs from find subs but it returns a promise function which is not accepted by the child process. How do I return subs

Comment: Use async await in findSubs()